# Design pattern for implementing the Polling approach in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, design-patterns, dataflow, system.timers.timer

I want to implement polling approach in c# using design patterns with some generic code with the below scenario.

I have 3 console application names Employee, Orders, Salary and in this from the Employee application I am initiating the Orders and Salary console application , once I will initiate application Orders and Salary console application are long running application which will keep on running and we are updating the local text file with the completion status for each of the application.

From the Employee application I have created a Timers objected and using Elapsed Event for 2 sec to check the file text whether it has status of both the file has been completed or not.

So I want to make the below implementation in more generic way or using some other approach/design patterns so that we can achieve the similar polling concept as I have ore complex situation where I have to use the same repetitive code for each time . Any suggestion on this ?

```
var poolingTimer = new Timer(2 * 1000);
poolingTimer.AutoReset = false;
poolingTimer.Elapsed += async delegate {
   if (logic to check if File text has console application completed status) {
      poolingTimer.Stop();    
   } else {
      poolingTimer.Start();
   }
};
poolingTimer.Start();
```

Comment: One thing in passing, if your timer is an instance of System.Threading.Timer then it implements IDisposable so you should wrap your timer instance in a using { ... } clause.

Comment: yes , its wrapped in my local code .. thx for pointing this. but do we have any way to implement the Timer Elapsed in more generic way/using design patterns so that I can reuse it in multiple place Or any alternative of Timer.Elapsed.

Comment: Why not use `FileSystemWatcher` instead of polling? Polling is invariably the wrong approach in modern systems.

Comment: because saving the file is just an example I may have different place where I am store the completed status for the polling purpose.